# snmptt running as non-root, writting to file as root

Tags: linux, snmp, zabbix

I'm running `snmptt` as a SNMP trap handler for `snmptrapd`, with the aim being to write to a trap file that can be read and processed by Zabbix.

I have set up snmptt to run as the `zabbix` user by changing the `init` script.

```
# grep daemon /etc/init.d/snmptt
# description: SNMP Trap Translator daemon
# Short-Description: SNMP Trap Translator daemon
OPTIONS="--daemon"
        daemon --user=zabbix /usr/sbin/snmptt $OPTIONS
```

`snmpttt` is running as expected as the `zabbix` user, the same user which is running the Zabbix server.

```
# ps -ef | grep snmp
root      3796     1  0 Jun19 ?        00:13:04 /usr/sbin/snmpd -LS0-6d -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid
zabbix    4444     1  0 15:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/snmptt --daemon
zabbix    4445  4444  0 15:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/snmptt --daemon
root      9300 29899  0 15:25 pts/2    00:00:00 grep snmp
zabbix   16576 16511  0 Aug16 ?        00:00:11 /path/to/sbin/zabbix_server: snmp trapper [processed data in 0.000007 sec, idle 1 sec]
root     16600     1  0 Aug16 ?        00:00:07 /usr/sbin/snmptrapd -A -Lf /var/log/snmptrapd.log -D -p /var/run/snmptrapd.pid
```

The log file to send traps caught is `/var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp`

```
# egrep "^(log_file|pid)" /etc/snmp/snmptt.ini
pid_file = /var/run/snmptt/snmptt.pid
log_file=/var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp
```

However, the trap log file is being written to, and owned by the `root` user, not as the `zabbix` user as expected. Moreover, the permissions on the file are `0640`, meaning that the zabbix user running the server is not able to read the file.

```
# service snmptt stop
Stopping snmptt:                                           [  OK  ]
# rm /var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp
rm: remove regular file `/var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp'? y
# ls -lia /var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp
ls: cannot access /var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp: No such file or directory
# ls -lia /var/tmp/zabbixtest/
total 24
263224 drwxrwxr-x 2 root zabbix 4096 Aug 17 15:32 .
262145 drwxrwxrwt 7 root root   4096 Aug 17 14:53 ..
# service snmptt start
Starting snmptt: PID file: /var/run/snmptt/snmptt.pid
                                                           [  OK  ]
# ps -ef | grep snmptt
zabbix    9944     1  0 15:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/snmptt --daemon
zabbix    9945  9944  0 15:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/snmptt --daemon
root      9981 29899  0 15:32 pts/2    00:00:00 grep snmptt
# ps -ef | grep snmp
root      3796     1  0 Jun19 ?        00:13:04 /usr/sbin/snmpd -LS0-6d -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid
zabbix    9944     1  0 15:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/snmptt --daemon
zabbix    9945  9944  0 15:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/snmptt --daemon
root      9986 29899  0 15:32 pts/2    00:00:00 grep snmp
zabbix   16576 16511  0 Aug16 ?        00:00:11 /path/to/sbin/zabbix_server: snmp trapper [processed data in 0.000079 sec, idle 1 sec]
root     16600     1  0 Aug16 ?        00:00:07 /usr/sbin/snmptrapd -A -Lf /var/log/snmptrapd.log -D -p /var/run/snmptrapd.pid
# ls -lia /var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp
262265 -rw-r----- 1 root root 122 Aug 17 15:32 /var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp
```

Note the file permissions and ownership of `/var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp`.

Accordingly, the `zabbix` user is unable to read the file and is hence unable to process it.

I can fix by manually modifying the mode of the trap file `/var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp` to `0644`, for example, but I am hoping there is a better way, e.g. via a configuration file, since the file location will most likely change. (There are some blog sites recommending to change the mode to 0777, obviously that is not the correct solution).

I guess it is due to the `snmptrapd` configuration, running as root, but not sure the best way to fix this.

**My questions:**

Why is the trap log file being written to as the `root` user with `0640` permissions, instead of as `zabbix` user running `snmptt`?

How can/should I configure `snmptt` and/or `snmptrapd` to have the trap file be owned and readable by the  `zabbix` user instead of root user.

**Other relevant info:**

snmptrapd config file:

```
# grep -v '^#' /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf
disableAuthorization yes

traphandle default /usr/sbin/snmptthandler
```

Running RHEL 6.6

Comment: Cannot spot anything obvious - are you sure the file has not been created earlier while running snmptt in standalone mode?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution at least after Richlv's comment about the file being created in standalone mode.

I made a few changes and got a working solution at least.

I think I had not restarted `snmptrapd` after changing `snmptrapd.conf` to read `traphandle default /usr/sbin/snmptthandler` instead of `traphandle default /usr/sbin/snmptt`.

**Why written as root**

A new instance of `snmptt` was being called by `snmptrapd`, which was running as root and must be to bind to snmp port 162. Therefore the files written by `snmptt` were owned by root also.

The permissions however, remains a mystery to me. I cannot tell where the `0640` permissions are coming from.

**Main changes believed to have fixed the issue**

1. Restart `snmptrapd` (`service snmptrapd restart`), which caused re-read of `snmptrapd.conf`, to ensure that `snmptthandler` is used for processing traps instead of `snmptt` , which had previously been written in the config file.

This does not fix entire issue, however, since now `snmptthandler` writes traps to the spool directory `/var/spool/snmptt`, which is subsequently read by `snmptt` daemon process:

```
# grep spool_directory /etc/snmp/snmptt.ini
spool_directory = /var/spool/snmptt/

# grep -A5 SPOOL /usr/sbin/snmptthandler
...
while (defined(my $line = <>))
{
        print SPOOL $line;

        if ($DEBUGGING >= 1)
        {
                # Print out item passed from snmptrapd
                print $line."\n";
        }
```

The spooled files will be owned by `root`, with the same permissions `0640` as was issue with log file from `snmptt` in standalone mode. That means the `snmptt` daemon process will still not be able to read and process them after `snmptthandler`  is finished. (In the log file `/var/log/snmptt/snmptt.debug`, there will be a `permissions denied` error when trying to read the spool file.)

So, the next step:

Set ownership of the spool directory to be the `snmptt` daemon user, and use the [set-gid](http://linuxg.net/how-to-set-the-setuid-and-setgid-bit-for-files-in-linux-and-unix/) on the spool directory, causing the new files written to be owned by, and readable by, the user running `snmptt`.

```
chown zabbix:zabbix /var/spool/smptt
chmod g+s /var/spool/smptt
#ls -lia /var/spool/snmptt/
total 8
209 drwxrwsr-x  2 zabbix zabbix 4096 Aug 18 11:40 .
#ps -ef | grep snmptt
zabbix    8787     1  0 12:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/snmptt --daemon
```

Following that, the `snmptt` daemon can read the spooled files, and will write the files into the expected log directory `/var/tmp/zabbixtest/zabbix_traps.tmp` as the `zabbix` user, not as root.

```
### After a trap is received 
# ls -lia /var/tmp/zabbixtest/snmptt.log
524605 -rw-rw-r--  1 zabbix zabbix   646 Aug 18 13:16 snmptt.log
```

The umask for the log file is from the `snmptt` script:

```
$ grep -i umask /usr/sbin/snmptt
#umask 0;
umask 002;
  #umask 0;
  umask 002;
```

**Other changes, good practice but not believe to have directly impacted the result**

1. Changed `snmptt.ini` to read `mode=daemon` instead of `mode=standalone`. (Not clear what effect this had, if any)
2. Change `/etc/snmp/snmptt.ini` to read `daemon_uid=` (blank) instead of `daemon_uid=zabbix` (this is recommended in [snmp docs](http://snmptt.sourceforge.net/docs/snmptt.shtml), and prevents the double `snmptt` processes by the same user.

So, there is a way to fix it. Not sure if it is the best way. Best way might include changing `snmptthandler` to use the user/umask defined in configuration file.

This doesn't answer full question (0640 permissions still not clear) Comments or assistance welcome for that.